# Vercel React app makes rest calls to http endpoints

Tags: reactjs, https, vercel

Hi I have a react application that runs on vercel so in https and the backend is on a vps, the backend has no https and when I run the rest calls from frontend to backend I have the following error how do I solve it?

**Error:**

```
xhr.js:220 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://vmgroupfrontend.vercel.app/#/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure
 XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myendpoint.org:3001/user/login'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: you need to serve the backend on https.

Comment: @technophyle now is not possible

Comment: I strongly recommend you to upgrade your backend to https but if you just want to test your app, you can downgrade your frontend to http.

Comment: @technophyle I'm not the systems engineer who takes care of this so I can't do it